# Is a file a document object?

Tags: java, xml, file, document

I'm pretty new to java servlets, so I'm a little confused on whether or not a txt, xml, or json file is considered a Document Object.

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is what do you mean by "Document Object"?

Comment: In java, there is a document class.  Document doc = null;

Comment: [`org.w3c.dom.Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)? No. None of a txt, xml or json file is an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given an exmaple. I meant the document in this link  https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/220790/xslt-transformation-from-a-servlet

Comment: Anyway, servlets don't care about your txt, xml or json files. They offer input/output through two mechanisms: the HttpServletRequest passed as parameter to the service() method, which, if a file was sent in the request, enables to read the file with getInputStream() or getReader(), that is to say as a stream of bytes. And the HttpServletResponse also passed as parameter to the service() method, which enables to write a response by getting getOutputStream() or getWriter() and writing to it, therefore another stream of bytes. Servlets don't care what are your files. They're bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`Document` is a Java class: an instance of `Document` is an in-memory tree structure. Actually there are several classes with this name, but you probably mean `org.w3c.dom.Document`. There are others such as JDOM2 or XOM Documents, but at a high level they are all tree representations of XML.

Converting angle-bracket XML contained in a file into a `Document` tree is a process called parsing; the reverse process is called serialization.

So an XML file and a Document object are alternative representations of the same information, but they are not the same thing.